# create a new ontology with Jena

Tags: classpath, jena, ontology

I'm trying to use Jena. For creating a new ontology my code is:

```
    String SOURCE = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#";
    String NS = SOURCE + "#";
    OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    ontology.read( SOURCE, "OWL/XML" );
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.<clinit>(Metadata.java:26)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.JenaRuntime.<clinit>(JenaRuntime.java:25)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.<clinit>(RDFReaderFImpl.java:85)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<clinit>(ModelCom.java:42)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:122)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:116)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL.<clinit>(OWL.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ProfileRegistry.<clinit>(ProfileRegistry.java:48)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec.<clinit>(OntModelSpec.java:54)
```

What's the problem?I couldn't find any solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java classpath is missing one of the jar files required by Jena. Looks like it's one of the `slf4j` jars. You need to have all the jar files that come with Jena on the classpath. How to set the classpath depends on your OS and/or IDE, but Google can help.

Comment: I have another question!While I'm saving the ontology it gives me this error:Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <server> Code: 57/REQUIRED_COMPONENT_MISSING in SCHEME: A component that is required by the scheme is missing.   What should I write instead of SOURCE?

Comment: You should ask new questions using the “Ask Question” button at the top, and not as a comment on an old answer! That way, more people see the question. That being said, if you open the `SOURCE` URL in your web browser you'll see that its format is `TURTLE` and not `OWL/XML` so you need to use that format in `Model.read()`.

Comment: I'm so sorry.I asked the question here because they were related to each other.Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a Jena distribution, all the jars needed are in the lib/ directory. You need them all on the classpath.

On Windows / cygwin:

```
javac -cp '<install dir>\lib\*;' MyClass.java
```

On Linux:

```
javac -cp '<install dir>/lib/*' MyClass.java
```

To run, the created `.class` needs to be in your path, too:

```
java -cp '.:<install dir>/lib/*' MyClass
```

If you use maven to get Jena, the dependencies are automatically pulled in.